# Volume of a given parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, volume

In the $ABCD-PQRS$ parallelepiped shown, $AH=\sqrt{39}$, $HS=\sqrt{57}$. Calculate its volume ($H$ belongs to base).
(Answer:$V=220,5\sqrt{13}$)

[image]

My progress:

I can only discover AS

$AS^2 =39+57 \implies AS = \sqrt{96} \therefore AS = 4\sqrt6$

but I can't find the base area..

Missing any information?

Comment: 39+37=76. $PH$ is angle bisector of $QPS$. Information is not enough to find base area.

Comment: $PH=\frac{AP\cos 53^\circ}{\cos 30^\circ}$, $AH=\sqrt{AP^2-PH^2}$, we can restore $AP$ value from $AH$. $HS=\sqrt{(PH\sin30^\circ)^2+(PS-PH\cos 30^\circ)^2}$, then we can restore $PS$ value from $HS$. But we cannot recover $PQ$. We can move point $Q$ in $PQ$ direction and problem statement will be satisfied, but volume will change.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu thanks for alert... I've already corrected

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu A colleague said that it is possible to get the answer if ABDC is a rhombus

Comment: If you add that $ABCD$ is rhombus, then $PQ=PS$ and you can get answer. See my previous comment about finding $AP$ and $PS$. $V=AH\cdot PS \cdot PQ \cdot \sin 60^\circ$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Can explain $PH = \frac{APcos53}{cos30}$

Comment: Let drop perpendiculars from $H$ to $PS$ and $PQ$. Let bases of perpendiculars are $E$ on $PS$ and $F$ on $PQ$. Then $AE\perp PS$ and $AF\perp PQ$. Then $\triangle APE=\triangle APF$. Then $AE=AF$, $PE=PF=AP\cos 53^\circ$. Then $\triangle AHE=\triangle AHF$. Then $HE=HF$. Then $\triangle HPE=\triangle HPF$. Then $\angle HPE=\angle HPF=\frac{\angle EPF}2=30^\circ$. Then $PH=\frac{AE}{\cos 30^\circ}=\frac{AP\, \cos 53^\circ}{\cos 30^\circ}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I understood but I can't get to the solution   $
PH = \frac{6AP}{5.\sqrt3}\therefore \boxed{PH=\frac{2\sqrt3}{5}}\\

AH^2=AP^2-PH^2\implies 39 = AP^2-\frac{12}{25}\therefore \boxed{AP = 5\sqrt3}\\
\sqrt39.\sqrt57=\sqrt{\frac{PH^2}{4}+({PS-\frac{PH\sqrt3}{2}})^2}\implies\\
2223=\frac{3}{25}+PS^2-\frac{6PS}{5}+\frac{9}{25}\implies 25PS^2-30PS-55563=0???\\
V = \sqrt{39}.PS^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: In my comment in part $AH$. $HS=\sqrt{\ldots}$ dot was not for the product, but for separating sentences, so you've added surplus $\sqrt{39}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  $\sqrt57=\sqrt{\frac{PH^2}{4}+({PS-\frac{PH\sqrt3}{2}})^2}\implies\\
57=\frac{3}{25}+PS^2-\frac{6PS}{5}+\frac{9}{25}\implies 25PS^2-30PS-1413=0\\
\boxed{PS = \frac{3}{5}(1+\sqrt{158})}\\
V = \sqrt{39}.PS^2.\frac{\sqrt3}{2}
$  I'm wrong in math but I still can't get the result

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu "PS" should be $7\sqrt3$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  I found a solution and posted it.. In your resolution it wouldn't be $PH= \frac{PE}{cos30^o}$ instead of $PH= \frac{AE}{cos30^o}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthogonally project $PA$ onto the base plane $PAsin(a)=PH$ then project it orthogonally onto $PS$ ($PAsin(a)cos(30°)$) which is the rectangular component of $AP$ in the direction of $PS$.
Now that same component is achieved if you project $PA$ orthogonally giving $PAcos(53°)$.

Let $\angle HAP = a$

$PA\cdot sin(a)cos(30°)=PA\cdot cos(53^o)\\
sin(a)=\frac{cos(53^o)}{cos(30°)}=\frac{\frac{3}{5}}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}=\frac{2\sqrt3}{5}\\
\therefore sec(a)=\frac{5}{\sqrt13}\\
PA =AH sec(a)=5\sqrt3\\
\triangle PAS (PA =5\sqrt{3}, AS=\sqrt{96})\implies PS=\sqrt{73}\\
V =(\sqrt{73})\cdot2sen(60^o)\cdot\sqrt{39}=220,5\sqrt{13}$

(By hMendez)